# JUnit, assertEquals false when two objects seem exactly the same

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm testing a Spring controller and I've mocked the loginService which I call in it.

I got errors in Unit Testing on the response of the controller but, as I can see in debug mode, the two elements compared seem exactly the same.

Below you can see the image of the debugger that shows that the two elements are equals.

Now let's see the code below.

System Under Test (RestController.class)

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

@Autowired
LoginService loginService;  
...
//METHOD BEING TESTED
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<JsonResponseBody> loginUser(@RequestParam(value ="id") String id, @RequestParam(value="password") String pwd){
    try {
        Optional<User> userr = loginService.getUserFromDbAndVerifyPassword(id, pwd);      //verify the presence into the database
        if (userr.isPresent()) {
            User user = userr.get();                                  //get the User from the optional got from the DB
            String jwt = loginService.createJwt(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPermission(), new Date());
            //set the jwt token into the header of response
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("jwt", jwt).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.OK.value(),"Success! User logged in." + jwt));
        }
    }catch(UserNotLoggedException e1){ //thrown by loginService#getUserFromDbAndVerifyPassword
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),"Login failed! Wrong credentials. " + e1.toString()));
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e2){  //thrown by loginService#createJwt
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),"Login failed! Encoding permission token error. " + e2.toString()));
    }
    //send response to client
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),"Login failed! No corrispondence found into the database of users."));
}

...
//INNER CLASS USING LOMBOK
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JsonResponseBody{
    @Getter @Setter
    private int server;
    @Getter @Setter
    private Object response;
}
...
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestControllerTest {

   @InjectMocks
   RestController restController;

   @Mock
   LoginService loginService;

   @Test
   public void loginUserWithSuccessTest() throws UserNotLoggedException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
       User user = new User("BDAGPP32E08F205K", "Pippo Baudo", "ILoveSanRemoEncrypted", "conduttore");
       Optional<User> fakeUserOptional = Optional.of(user);
       when(loginService.getUserFromDbAndVerifyPassword("BDAGPP32E08F205K","ILoveSanRemo")).thenReturn(fakeUserOptional);

       String jwt = "aaaa.bbbb.cccc";
       when(loginService.createJwt(eq(user.getId()), eq(user.getUsername()), eq(user.getPermission()), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(jwt);

       ResponseEntity serverResponse = restController.loginUser("BDAGPP32E08F205K","ILoveSanRemo");
       RestController.JsonResponseBody responseBody = restController.new JsonResponseBody(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Success! User logged in." + jwt);

       assertEquals(serverResponse.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK); //TRUE

       boolean areTheyEquals=false;
       if((RestController.JsonResponseBody) serverResponse.getBody() == responseBody){
           areTheyEquals = true;
       }
       assertEquals(areTheyEquals, true); //FALSE?!?!?!?!?
       assertThat((RestController.JsonResponseBody) serverResponse.getBody(), is(responseBody)); //FALSE?!?!?!
    }
}
```

The last two asserts result false. When I debug this test I discover how the mock seems to be correct and also, before the asserts the two objects being compared seem absolutely equals.
The error given by JUnit is this:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: is
> com.example.bytecode.SpringBootJWT.controllers.RestController$JsonResponseBody@587c290d
>
> but: was
> com.example.bytecode.SpringBootJWT.controllers.RestController$JsonResponseBody@4516af24

Below you can see the image of the debugger.

[image: The Debugger Tab shows how the two elements being compared (serverResponse.body and responseBody) seem exactly equal. But the last two asserts are false]

Comment: assertEquals()doesn't care if two objects A and B look exactly the same. It tests if A.equals(B) is true or false. So it's entirely dependant on the implementation of the equals() method (if any) of JsonResponseBody. Note however that you're not testing the equality of two objects. You're testing the equality of areTheyEquals with true (which would be much clearer to express with `assertTrue(areTheyEquals)`). And areTheyEquals is set to true only if the new responseBody you created is the exact same object (you're comparing with ==) as the body of the response, which can't possibly be true.

Comment: you are comparing objects using ==

Comment: areTheyEquals has been added laterly because I wasn't able to understand why the last assert is false. My question is: how can I adjust the last assert (not the one regarding areTheyEquals)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different types of assertion in this block:

```
boolean areTheyEquals=false;
if((RestController.JsonResponseBody) serverResponse.getBody() == responseBody){
    areTheyEquals = true;
}
assertEquals(areTheyEquals, true); //FALSE?!?!?!?!?
assertThat((RestController.JsonResponseBody) serverResponse.getBody(), is(responseBody)); //FALSE?!?!?!
```

It's unclear whether your code ever reaches the second assertion (`assertThat(...)`) but a few things are clear:

- Asserting equality using `==` will only work if you are comparing the **same** instance
- If `assertThat((RestController.JsonResponseBody) serverResponse.getBody(), is(responseBody))` fails then the `equals()` method on `RestController.JsonResponseBody` has deemed these two instances to be different so either:

  - The `equals()` method on `RestController.JsonResponseBody` does not do what you expect it to do
  - These two instances of `RestController.JsonResponseBody` are genuinely different
  - (Most likely) There is no `equals()` method on `RestController.JsonResponseBody` so it is just calling `super` to a parent which just evaluates object equality

I would suggest:

1. Add an `equals()` method on `RestController.JsonResponseBody` or just use Mockito's `refEq()` to apply a simple, reflection based equality check
2. Remove this assertion: `assertEquals(areTheyEquals, true);`

Comment: The first assertion has been added laterly because I wasn't able to understand why the last assert doesn't work. I don't have the equals () method. I still don't get why they are considered different. Are really the same!

Comment: @AlexMawashi When you assert like this: `assertThat((RestController.JsonResponseBody) serverResponse.getBody(), is(responseBody));` then you are asking `RestController.JsonResponseBody.equals()` to decide if they "are really the same" so if that assertion does not pass then they are **not** really the same. If you feel that they are sufficiently "the same" for your needs then implement `RestController.JsonResponseBody.equals()` such that it meets your expectations. In your current position you are leaving it up to `equals()` to decide if they are the same and then disagreeing with its decision